# Jupyter Lab で sympy.init_session() を用いるとそれ以降のセルが動かなくなる

Tags: python, anaconda, sympy, jupyter-lab

Sympyをimportし`init_session()` 又は `init_printing()`を用いるとそれ以後のセルが[*]となってしまいどれだけ待っても実行されません。
Jupyter notebookを使用しても同様の問題が生じます。

[image: init_session()以降が動かない]

コンソール上のIpython上では`init_session()`を行っても正常に動作します。

[image: コマンドラインでの挙動]

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: init_session()
IPython console for SymPy 1.6.2 (Python 3.8.5-64-bit) (ground types: python)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

Documentation can be found at https://docs.sympy.org/1.6.2/


In [3]: fx = sin(x)*cos(x)**3

In [4]: fx
Out[4]:
          3
sin(x)⋅cos (x)
```

`init_session()`をコメントアウトすると正常に動作します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

anacondaを2度再インストールしましたが同様の問題に悩まされています。

**環境:**
Windows10 -64bit
anaconda 4.9.2
Python 3.8.5.final.0
sympy 1.6.2
Jupyter lab 2.2.6
notebook 6.1.4

Comment: windows10、python3.8.6、sympy1.6.2で再現しました。ですが、「init_session()」は必要ですか？

Comment: `sympy`の版数か、`sympy`と`jupyter`関連あるいは`python`との版数問題かもしれませんね。`Anaconda`ではない`Python 3.8.6`環境の`sympy 1.7`,`jupyterlab 2.2.9`,`notebook 6.1.5`では正常に動作しています。

Comment: init_session()はinit_printing()やx, yなどの変数のシンボライズを自動的にやってくれるため必要です。
特に行列を表示する際にきれいになるので愛用しています。

Comment: 私の場合、｢init_printing()｣なら問題なく動作しました。jupyter labは2.2.9です。 ※pythonはanacondaではありません。

Comment: Anacondaの2020.11版をインストールしてConsoleで全モジュールをconda update conda および conda update --allすればsympyも1.7に上がって質問のソースでも正常に動作するようです。